# What is the right syntax for .less variable interpolation?

Tags: less, dotless

I've got a .less stylesheet with the following construct:

```
@width:600;

.some-style
{
    width:@{width}px;
}
```

and this gives the following error:

```
Expected '}' on line x in file '..\styles.less'
```

I need those braces, because I need to distinguish the variable from the following `px` suffix (`@widthpx` doesn't work because then it looks for a variable called `widthpx`).  And I can't use a space because `600 px` isn't valid css.  Using parentheses instead of curly braces doesn't work either.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Update**: I installed the latest version of .less from the Package Manager, and now it works a little better, but with a fatal flaw:

```
   width:@(width)px;  <--note the parentheses
```

now compiles, but emits this CSS:

```
  600 px  <--note the space, which is invalid CSS, thus useless.
```

**Solved**: ScottS pointed me to the solution.  In addtion to his two methods, it looks like the compiler can do math on string.  So this works:

```
@width:600px;

.some-style
{
    width:@width / 2;  <--correctly emits "300px"
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you want to give the `width` a value but without any units, and assign the units at the time of the call. I'm not sure ***why*** you would want to do that, but there are two ways that would work:

**ONE**: make the `width` a string and then do a string interpolation:

```
@width: '600';

.some-style
{
    width: ~'@{width}px';
}
```

**TWO**: multiply by `1px`:

```
@width: 600;

.some-style
{
    width: @width * 1px;
}
```

I've left the above answers in place for a case of "unitless" numbers and how to add the unit later (as the question appeared to be at first). However, based on your comment let me explain why `@width: 600px` works. LESS does not see that as a *string* (as you mention you view it). Rather, it sees it as a number with units. To LESS `600px` is not the string of characters (unless it is wrapped in quotes), but the number `600` in units of `pixels`. This is why it can do operations on it just fine, without you having to worry about it. It can do so whether those units are `em` or `%` or any other valid CSS unit.

Comment: The reason is so that I can do math with the units.  For instance, I want to do width: @{width / 2}px.  But I just checked and it looks like the compiler actually does understand this.  If I change my original definition to @width:600px, and then set the style to be width:@width / 2, the compiler correctly emits 300px. To me it's counter-intuitive that the math is done on the string 600px rather than the number 600, but it solves my problem.  Could you please update your answer (or add a new one) with this solution, and I'll accept it? The above solution really isn't what solves the problem.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank: perhaps I had beat you too it before you posted the comment. I obviously misunderstood your reason to not put units originally on `@width`. I will update the answer to help explain why this is _not_ "counter-intuitive" as you believe it to be.

Answer (score 0):

There is also better way by using [unit](http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-unit) function:

```
@width: 600;

.some-style
{
    width: unit(@width, px);
}
```

If you do this frequently then you can define [mixin](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-mixins-as-functions-feature):

```
.widthInPx(@w)
{
    width: unit(@w, px);
}

.some-style
{
    .widthInPx(@width);
}
```